# About Reporting Server Permissions

Tags: c#, reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I have an ASP.NET application that runs under Classic .NET AppPool.

I'm trying to render a report hosted in Reporting Services in another machine, with the correct address and everything. But I keep getting the following error, which I just can't solve:

Cannot create a connection to data source 'MYDATASOURCE'. (rsErrorOpeningConnection) ---> Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportServerException: Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\IUSR'.

I won't post any code, I'm simply calling the .Render() method through Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.

Could it be a configuration or some special permission I have to grant to my code?

Any Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Granting permission directly on the database to the user NT AUTHORITY\IUSR solved the problem. I'm not very sure about security issues doing this, but thats another question.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When I created something similar we set up a service account for the app pool the asp.net application to run as/under.  Then gave that service account permissions to run the reports we wanted to display.  I had to work with our DBA and System Engineers to set up the service accounts and permissions on the reporting server.  But once that was all done it worked out slick.  I am not sure it was all necessary, but that is how we did.

I am not a very experienced web developer, so I hope my terminology is correct and makes sense.

cheers

Answer (score 0):

in your report manager grant sufficient permissions to this : `NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE`